# Reference Request - Surface Area as the limit of a sequence of areas of polyhedral approximations

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, reference-request

What is a reference that explains surface area as the limit of a sequence of the areas of polyhedral approximations? (Ideally, it would also explain the [Schwarz Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern).)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern#Relation_to_arc_length_and_surface_area), "the Schwarz lantern shows that surface area cannot be defined as the supremum of inscribed polyhedral surfaces".

Comment: Could you give us the references you already know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L. V. Toralballa wrote several articles on this question:

[1] Alpert, Louis I.; Toralballa, L. V. [An elementary definition of surface area in $E^{n+1}$ for smooth surfaces](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/toralballa%20elementary.pdf). *Pacific J. Math.* **40** (1972), 261--268.

[2] Toralballa, L. V. [A geometric theory of surface area. I. Non-parametric surfaces](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/toralballa1.pdf). *Monatsh. Math.* **74** (1970), 462--476.

[3] Toralballa, L. V. [A geometric theory of surface area. II](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/toralballa2.pdf). Triangulable parametric surfaces. *Monatsh. Math.* **76** (1972), 66--77.

[3] Toralballa, L. V. Corrigenda: "A geometric theory of surface area. II. Triangulable parametric surfaces''. *Monatsh. Math.* **77** (1973), 156--157.

[4] Toralballa, L. V. [A geometric theory of surface area. III](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/surface%20area%203.pdf). Non-triangulable parametric surfaces. *Monatsh. Math.* **77** (1973), 363--365.

For the Schwarz Lantern, you can look at

[5] Frieda Zames, [Surface Area and the Cylinder Area Paradox](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/00494925.di020678.02p0385w.pdf), *The Two-Year College Mathematics Journal* **8**, No. 4 (Sep., 1977), pp. 207-211